# Fetch a file from ruTorrent via another server with wget/other command

Tags: php, http, ssh, get, wget

So the setup:

A server(seedbox) running rtorrent/rutorrent with no access to filesystem.

- https secured with invalid cert
- Basic HTTP Authentication

The server I want to download the files to is a centos server with full root ssh access.

I can successfully fetch data from rutorrent by using this wget command:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --user=myusername --password=mypassword https://mysite.tld/rutorrent/images/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png
```

My problem is with the "get file" feature where you can download a file from a torrent through http on you browser. This works fine when using a browser.
But I want to fetch that file to my centos ssh-accessible server.
The link that is produced for "get file" is in this format:

```
https://mysite.tld/rutorrent/plugins/data/action.php?hash=########################################&no=0
```

And when wget is used with my syntax above, all it fetches is:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 39 [text/html]
Saving to: “action.php?hash=########################################”

100%[======================================>] 39          --.-K/s   in 0s

2015-04-01 01:00:00 (2.82 MB/s) - “action.php?hash=########################################” saved [39/39]
```

I haven't the first clue on how to use wget or any other command to fetch the file itself in the same way a browser can process the request and get the actual file.

the code for action.php is:

```
<?php
require_once( '../../php/xmlrpc.php' );

if(isset($_REQUEST['result']))
    cachedEcho('noty(theUILang.cantAccessData,"error");',"text/html");

if(isset($_REQUEST['hash']) && isset($_REQUEST['no']))
{
    $req = new rXMLRPCRequest( 
        new rXMLRPCCommand( "f.get_frozen_path", array($_REQUEST['hash'],intval($_REQUEST['no']))) );
    if($req->success())
    {
        $filename = $req->val[0];
        if($filename=='')
        {
            $req = new rXMLRPCRequest( array(
                new rXMLRPCCommand( "d.open", $_REQUEST['hash'] ),
                new rXMLRPCCommand( "f.get_frozen_path", array($_REQUEST['hash'],intval($_REQUEST['no'])) ),
                new rXMLRPCCommand( "d.close", $_REQUEST['hash'] ) ) );
            if($req->success())
                $filename = $req->val[1];
        }
        if(sendFile($filename))
            exit;
    }
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['readable']))
    cachedEcho("Cant retrieve such large file, sorry","text/html");
else
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily");
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?result=0');
}
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: To be clear, are you using `wget` on the PNG URL, or the `action.php` URL?

Comment: The png url was an example that it works, I am trying to get the file throught the action.php url

Comment: OK. What is contained within the downloaded file from the PHP script? It seems to be 39 bytes long, and of type `text/html` - seems like you need a `Content-Type` header. Can we see the PHP code?

Comment: This is the php code for action.php:

http://rutorrent.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/plugins/data/action.php

Comment: ^ Great. Would you add it into your question please, we tend to discourage external links here, as they are subject to breakage.

Comment: OK, that makes for a better question. What is inside the 39 byte file? There are two cases where a `text/html` response may be returned, so I would look into them.

Comment: This was the 39byte file I opened with with nano:

`noty(theUILang.cantAccessData,"error");`

(39 characters long)

Comment: Well, it's fairly clear what's happening, isn't it? The code to fetch the binary data is not being executed, and instead you have some code that is rendering text instead. Find out if the clause on lines 3-4 is responsible, and if so, stop it happening. Is `$_REQUEST['result']` set in this situation?